# WPF Data trigger causing flash while loading animation

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I have a data trigger which upon set to false hide the related controls with animation. Now when the screen is being loaded values of the properties are already false, still it run the animation and fade the controls thus hide them.

It is causing a brief flash on screen.

I expect those controls to remain hidden on screen until I set the property to true.

```
   <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="somestyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsControlVisible,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1.5"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1.5"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Width="100" Height="50" Content="Toggle Visibiity" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Width="200" Height="50" Content="Something Something" Margin="0 20 0 0" Style="{StaticResource somestyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: In the load method make StackPanel visible = false at beginning of the load.  Then last instruction in load Panel make StackPanel visible = true.

Comment: @jdweng There is no instruction in load method, so the only two statements would be StackPanelVisible=false and StackPanelVisible=true

Comment: You said : "screen is being loaded".  So I guess you mean constructed?  There is an Initialize() occurring and then a default Load() method is occurring.  So you need to add a Load method with the three instructions (not just the two you posted).  The third instruction is to call the base.Load() method between the visible = false and the visible = true;

Comment: Is your `IsControlVisible` per default `true` and you set it false? I mean in the `DependencyProperty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when your control is loaded and the style is applied, the trigger is evaluated and, since initially `IsControlVisible` is `false`, the first storyboard is started, animating the `Opacity` from 1 (default value) to 0. So the solution is to set the initial `Opacity` value to 0 (or, better yet, to a value corresponding to the initial value of `IsControlVisible`). To do that it is sufficient to add an appropriate setter to your style:

```
<Style x:Key="somestyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="{Binding IsControlVisible, Mode=OneTime}" />
    (...)
</Style>
```

It is advisable to set the binding mode to `OneTime` so that when the value of `IsControlVisible` changes later on, the `Opacity` is only controlled by the animations and not the binding. Also, I didn't use any converter, but as it turns out the framework is smart enough to properly convert `bool` to `double`.

Comment: Where were you all this time :-) . Thanks it works like a charm

Comment: @Amazing knowledge !